# Old movie where young astronaut returns to Earth very aged

Tags: story-identification, movie

It was about an astronaut who went into space, young guy, and came back. In the hospital, the doctors are looking at him in shock after he came back. We don’t see his face yet, then there is a sudden close up of him. He is a grizzled old man.

It's possibly from the 50s or 60s.

It was definitely a movie and the astronaut wasn't in space for very long. It would have been in the theatre in the early 60's but that's all I can recall, unfortunately.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*[Beyond the Time Barrier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beyond_the_Time_Barrier)* (1960).

[image]

In 1960, U.S. Air Force Major Bill Allison pilots an experimental aircraft on a sub-orbital spaceflight, during which he loses radio contact with Earth.

When he returns to Earth, the base he launched from is decrepit and deserted, and there's a futuristic city on the horizon. It transpires that he's now in the year 2024, and humanity has not fared well in the intervening period.

Near the end of the film, he returns to his own time via another sub-orbital flight, and is taken to hospital, where he's revealed to have aged drastically.

[image]

[The whole film](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HW-xqqPhIc0) is up on YouTube.

Answer (score 19):

The Twilight Zone, Season 5 episode 15 [The Long Morrow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Long_Morrow).

> Commander Douglas Stansfield, age 31, an astronaut in the year 1987, is scheduled in six months to be sent on an exploratory mission to a planetary system roughly 141 light-years from Earth. Although the spacecraft will travel at the rate of 7 times the speed of light, the round trip will still take forty years. To save him the ordeal of 40 years of loneliness, he is to be placed in (newly developed) suspended animation for the twenty-year trip to his goal, and again for the twenty-year return trip. During his time in suspended animation, he will age only a few weeks.
>
> Shortly before his mission, he meets and is enchanted by his young colleague, Sandra Horn. They meet that night, after only three and half hours, they declare their love for each other, and lament the fact that when Stansfield returns, Sandra will be an old woman.
>
> Forty years later, Stansfield returns to Earth, a forgotten pioneer. The discoveries he made on his mission were independently achieved earlier by technology developed after his departure. Sandra is waiting for him, still 26 and lovely. She had herself put in suspended animation during Stansfield's mission. Stansfield, however, had voluntarily disabled his suspended-animation system six months into his journey after a communications failure on his ship, and is now a man of 70.

Comment: I remember that episode, and thinking it reminds me of O Henry's *The Gift of the Magi*.

Comment: I remember this episode across nearly 60 years and like Stansfield, I too have become old. I was too young to have seen it in first run, but I saw a rerun probably a couple years after the show originally aired. I distinctly remember an adult explaining the story to me, because at 6 or 7, the plot was a little hard to follow. Imagine that the female star is still with us --- not so many adult actors from the TZ (original series) are with us, but I am surprised every once in a while. Shatner comes to mind -- but none are less than 80, I think -- I wonder if any surviving actor is over 100?

Answer (score 4):

Judging from this one scene, I would say this is the 1960 'Beyond the Time Barrier' with Robert Clarke. Clarke plays a test pilot flying a new plane - he flies into a time warp and ends up in the distant year 2024 where nuclear fallout has driven humanity underground. He manages to fly back through the warp to warn the people of 1960 about the dangers of nuclear weapons, but loses his youth in the process. The final shot of his wrinkled face shocked the hell out of me when I saw it as a kid.